# How can I get a token using the Authorization Code flow in a terminal?

Tags: php, openid-connect

I want to request a token using Authorization Code flow, but I don't want to have a graphical browser pop up when I'm in a terminal, so I want to supply what it needs on the command line.

I've found a php program

[oauth command line](https://github.com/aaronpk/command-line-oauth)

, but this doesn't work.

It first stops on the "open" command.

```
sh: line 1: open: command not found
```

I've tried replacing open with xdg-open, but it seems it's not building a complete URL.

Comment: _"but I don't want to have a graphical browser pop up"_ - and a script that contains the line `echo "Open the following URL in a browser to continue\n";` would do what instead, according to your interpretation ...?

Comment: _"but it seems it's not building a complete URL"_ - the value of `$authorize_url` gets output on the line before, so you should be able to quickly verify whether that is a correct URL to invoke the authorization dialog, or not.

Comment: Right, I see now that it actually opens a graphical browser with a return url to its own instantiated server, but that's not what I wanţ so I have to figure out where I can ask a general question, then;). Thanks, anyways.

Comment: OAuth usually _requires_ user interaction (unless you have a provider that allows you to create a token by directly sending login credentials to some endpoint, but I'm not sure if that would even still technically be OAuth then.)

Comment: Well, the only "user interaction" would be filling in username and password and then clicking login. That should easily be automated. There are other authorization flows in OAuth, but the ones I intend to automate against, are just using Authorization Code.